# How to manipulate dates in sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I want to manipulate dates within the Spark framework. But I can not. See my code:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


my_con <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "3.0.0")

df <- structure(list(x = c("19991123", NA, "19980101")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df_1 <- sdf_copy_to(sc = my_con, x = df)

class(df_1)
#[1] "tbl_spark" "tbl_sql"   "tbl_lazy"  "tbl"  

df_1 %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., my_date = as_date(x))
```

But:

```
  x        my_date   
  <chr>    <date>    
 1 19991123 NA        
 2 NA       NA        
 3 19980101 NA
```

`NA`s are produced. What's happens?

Comment: `to_date("19991123", "yyyyMMdd")` where the number part might be a column

Comment: What is the `to_date` library?

Comment: spark function.